# Did North Korean officials focus a probe on whether fire victims tried to save portraits?

Tags: north-korea

The [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8596057/North-Korea-Officials-probe-explosion-victims-tried-save-Kim-portraits.html) recently reported that North Korean officials are investigating some people's response to a gas explosion. In particular, they are focussed on whether the obligatory portraits of Kim Il-sung and Kim Jong-il were saved.

> North Korean officials investigating a series of gas explosions that killed at least nine people are focusing their probe on whether families in Hyesan did everything they could to save portraits of the Kim dictators.
>
> [...]
>
> Earlier this year, a North Korean mother was threatened with jail after saving her two children from a house fire but allowed portraits of North Korea's leaders to burn.

There is no evidence given. I think it was fabricated.

Is there evidence for this?

Comment: https://www.dailynk.com/english/mother-faces-punishment-failing-save-kim-family-portraits/

Comment: @DavePhD There are other web sites too. None of those sites give hard evidence. I wonder where these thinly-sourced horror stories originate from.

Comment: Closing while the question is fixed. This question assumes the answer.

Comment: I have edited the question to bring it into scope. The original question started with the conclusion that the report was false, and that the falsehood must have some traceable origin. I've edit to ask *if* the report is false, which is on-topic.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_NK) *Daily NK* (linked by @DavePhD) is published in **South** Korea. [Another story](https://www.dailynk.com/english/kim-il-sung-portrait-cannot-be-mor/) relates the tale of a woman who fled from North to South Korea after her father sold the glass taken from a portrait of Kim to pay for food.

Comment: Similar stories exist.  An English documentary about NK that aired in Hong Kong in the early-2000s showed citizens bringing Kim statues to a bomb shelter during a drill.